# MySQL pagination of text with HTML tags

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, pagination

I have a huge amount of text with HTML tags inside. All the text is in a MySql DB column of type ‘text’. The tags are not escaped.

I need to paginate it, i.e. 1000 chars on page, however if I use a simple SUBSTRING function like `SELECT SUBSTRING(text, 0, 1000)` it will probably cut the HTML tags, and I will have errors on a page.

For example:

`Text text. <p class='paragraph'>Next paragraph</p>`

may be cut like

`Text text. <p c` and `lass='paragraph'>Next paragraph</p>`.

So how can I get on every page next 'around 1000' chars from DB considering HTML tags?

Full text is around 5440676 chars, so it would be nice to paginate it using MySql, not PHP.

The site is on WordPress.

Comment: You can't do this with MySQL as it doesn't understand HTML. PHP can do it with the right module. You need an HTML parser with an understanding of how to cut and manipulate HTML documents, but even then this is extremely error-prone.

Comment: Maybe you could just get 1000 chars and use a regular expression `!<.*[^>]$!` on the end of the string to check whether there has been an opening `<` without the closing equivalent, and if so, cut the slice out and prepend it to the next 1000 chars. But this is not very nice.

Comment: Improved grammar and add spacing to improve readability.

Comment: @CarlosRamirezIII thank you so much!

Comment: @Michael that's how I think, but you're right, it's not so good..